# How to navigate to a HTML page from an ACTIVITY in android

Tags: android, html

I'm working in a webview and I'm successfully redirecting from home.html to MainActivity but I want to back go to home.html.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}

public void logout(View view)
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", 0);
    if (preferences.contains("userphoto")) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.remove("userphoto");
        editor.remove("userbg");
        editor.commit();

        finish();
    }
}

public void back(View view)
{
finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to navigate through a webpage within the app, you can use a `WebView`. It makes it easier to navigate through the webpage and app seamlessly.

Here's an example solution: I would check if the user can go back using `webView.canGoBack()` and if so go back using `webView.goBack()`. Otherwise exit the activity with `finish()`.

```
@Override public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
        return;
    }
    finish();
}
```

[Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Comment: Glad I could help - please mark my answer as answered if it's what you were looking for!

Comment: I am looking for the image picker from gallery in html can you help me.

Comment: Ask another question on Stack Overflow :)